# How to get hour from crontab and sort by order when store in mysql?

Tags: mysql, cron

I have a feild that store crontab ,now I want to sort the tablee accordring to the crontab hour,how to write the sql?
For example,the crontab field is :

```
7 9 9 */1 * ?, 
0 9 8 */1 * ?,
0 9 19 */1 * ?;
```

I want the result is

```
0 9 8 */1 * ?, 
7 9 9 */1 * ?,
0 9 19 */1 * ?;
```

Now I can only write the sql like this:

```
select * from tb_student order by crontab  desc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `Seconds` is not Mandatory for crontab expression and there might be some Special characters as below [tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron#CRON_expression).

| Field name | Mandatory? | Allowed values | Special characters |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Seconds | No | 0-59 | `* / , -` |
| Minutes | Yes | 0-59 | `* / , -` |
| Hours | Yes | 0-23 | `* / , -` |
| Day of month | Yes | 1-31 | `* / , - L W` |
| Month | Yes | 1-12 or JAN-DEC | `* / , -` |
| Day of week | Yes | 0-6 or SUN-SAT | `* / , - L #` |
| Year | No | 1970–2099 | `* / , -` |

if we make sure the hour will be number and as same format.

```
0 9 19 */1 * ?
```

We can try to use `SUBSTRING_INDEX` to get part of your expect order number.

```
SELECT *
FROM T
ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Crontab, ' ', 3), ' ', -1) AS SIGNED)
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c7867c15a2f72fe54572377721e08a64)

IMHO, I would create a column to store a value which can create an index and improve the performance if your want to use that be order or filter condition instead of `order by` crontab column.